# Software Updater could not update

Tags: updates

I have 2 computers with the same model, https://www.bee-link.com/beelink-mini-s-n5095-mini-pc and the same OS, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
One computer, Software Updater could not update for a few days.
This is the result:

```
bl00004@bl00004:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for bl00004:
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:3 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (192.100.77.186), connection timed out
Err:4 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (192.100.77.186), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
bl00004@bl00004:~$
```

And another computer took a long time to shut down.

It happened at the same period of time.

What should be done to solve these problem ?

In our office we use only Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't find the reference just now but ISTR there was a question about this before for which the answer was that Canonical spread the update load across the user base so not everyone is "hit" at the same time if there is an issue.

Comment: The repository mirror server you are using (in Thailand?) may be down for some reason. Try again later, maybe? The long time to shut down may not be related. Here you have to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Your output clearly shows that the problem with the system-that-wouldn't-update seems to be at your end: `101: Network is unreachable`. That's not an Ubuntu software issue -- that's a your-network issue. Were the problem at the server, you would get a 300-series or 400-series error. Insufficient data to determine if your takes-too-long-to-shutdown system is related to your network problem or has some other cause.

Comment: Each of the "`Err:`" lines mentions an IPv6 address (`.(2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34`) Try; open your network settings and disable IPv6. Looks like somebody isn't fully IPv6. Fall back to IPv4.

Comment: @user68186
I switched from 'Server for Thailand' to 'Main server'. Now, Software Updater works smoothly. And I will use your comment as the answer of this question.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Thailand, after switching the **Setting** of **Software Updater** from **Server for Thailand** to **Main Server**. The problem has gone. And I will try to switch back to **Server for Thailand** everyday to check if it will be available.